# Advantage of <h:graphicImage> over <img>

Tags: jsf-2, tags, image

What are the advantages of using `<h:graphiImage>` over normal `<img>` (in terms of performance e.g. parse/render time, possible http caching if any?, etc.) for JSF2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get [server-side](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_graphicImage.html) [attributes](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/graphicImage.html) on `<img>` elements.

Comment: You mean something like `rendered`? this can be achieved through ui:fragment. Isn't there anything more special? For example does it give you any advantage when all your images are streamed by a single servlet.

Comment: Yes, `rendered` is one such attribute. I'm not sure what you're looking for in terms of "special" - there's no magic here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no safe and easy way to set an absolute path for the `src` attribute. This is important because you may well be referencing the same image from multiple pages that reside in different directories. Would you want the hassle of maintaining their relative location? Sure, you can use `<img src="#{resource['images:myImage.png']}"/>` to get a safe absolute path. Wouldn't it just be easier to use `<h:graphicImage name="myImage.png" library="images"/>`?

**What's this about a "safe" absolute path?**

You could leave your images outside the usual resources folder and specify them in an absolute path like this, for example: `<img src="/myApp-web/faces/images/myImage.png"/>` and that would work. But then what happens when you want to deploy your app? Do you want your URLs to be like `http://www.mysite.com/faces/myPage.xhtml`? Of course not. You want to set the context root to the server root. But you don't want the hassle of changing all your `img` tags for a production deployment, nor do you want some hack that involves getting the base URL from an application-scoped bean and hoping you remember to change a property for production deployment. So you're better off, at the very least, using `<img src="#{resource['images:myImage.png']}"/>` or the much easier to remember  `<h:graphicImage name="myImage.png" library="images"/>`.

Comment: You can always put context root before image src: `<img src="#{request.contextPath}/img/image.png"/>` which is both safe and easy.

Comment: Ah yes, didn't think of that, which is strange because I did it myself once. Still I think using the image component without EL is easier to do than the img tag with EL.